# how to find if a string contains numbers followed by a specific string

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
String str = "Friday 1st August 2013"
```

I need to check: if the string contains "any number" followed by the "st" string, print "yes", else print "no".

I tried: `if ( str.matches(".*\\dst") )` and `if ( str.matches(".*\\d.st") )` but it doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
if ( str.matches(".*\\dst.*") )
```

[`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) matches the regex pattern from beginning of the string to the end. The anchors `^` and `$` are implicit. So, you should use the pattern that matches the complete string.

Or, use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method, to search for a particular pattern anywhere in a string:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\dst").matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // ok
}
```

Comment: +1 but why mention the Pattern/find? It's not necessary and it's more code and less readable. Your explanation of why his matches didn't work and how to fix it is the real and best answer.

Comment: @Bohemian. It would add to OP knowledge :) Doesn't do any harm I guess. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can be used to match such pattern. e.g.

```
 String str = "Friday 1st August 2013"
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+st");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(mathcer.find())
      //yes
    else
     //no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
.*?(\\d+)st.*
```

The `?` after the `*` is necessary because `*` is "greedy" (it will match the entire string). `*?` does a "non-greedy" match. Also, the number can have more than a single digit (for example "15st").